# Low Quality Post review is unreadable

Tags: bug, status-norepro, review, design, low-quality-posts

I opened up a [Low Quality Post review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/71181), and the visuals on it are horrendous. It's borderline impossible to read the content of the post, and the Stack Exchange logo along with the Home, Question, etc. buttons are visible. Well, mostly visible. They're also hot links, they redirect to their related pages.

This isn't normal behavior for sure.

Screenshot:

[image]

I opened this logged in and out and viewed the same results on Chrome ver. 80.0.3987.149, and Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0

Running on Windows 10 version 1909 (OS Build 18363.720)

#### Update

Completely removed all extensions from Chrome, restarted, and I'm still seeing the same thing on this review in particular.

Upon pressing either Looks OK, Recommend Deletion, or Skip, I'm simply left with "loading next item..." indefinitely, completely shutting me down from continuing. Pressing "Edit" opens up the text editor correctly, but of course I don't want to edit the post, so I'm afraid to attempt to save edits.

[image]

Comment: No repro on Windows 10, Firefox 74.0

Comment: @Jenayah Strange, I went ahead and downloaded Firefox 74.0 and was still able to reproduce.

Comment: Userscript breaking a page maybe?

Comment: Reproducible. [Firefox 74.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxzTX.png) on Ubuntu 18.04, [Google Chrome 80.0.3987.149](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAUkw.png) on Ubuntu 18.04 and [Firefox 68.6.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx2GE.jpg) on Samsung Galaxy running One UI 2.0 (Android 10)

Comment: Confirming finding.  . I found a possibly related Bug where the next review won't load:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLENh.jpg - the other queues seem to work correctly (at least the CV one does). Confirmed on Chrome too: https://i.stack.imgur.com/87Rxy.jpg

Comment: Workaround if your review decision can't be accepted is to go to the question and flag as VLQ directly, that should prevent you from getting the review again a few minutes later.

Comment: Similar bug report on [math.meta.se]: [I am experiencing difficulty in the rendering of posts in the “review first posts queue.”](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31361)

Comment: Repro'd here in Firefox (with userscripts) and Safari (without) on macOS.

Comment: Tried to open this again. Appears it's been [fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/71181) and I was able to perform a review action. I'm curious, now, how @Glorfindel managed to "Close" in a Low Quality Post review.

Comment: I tried a few things 'under the hood' to test how broken the queue actually was. I've voted to delete the post via the regular pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the [review is no longer visually messy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/71181).

Despite @Glorfindel managing to "Close" through a LQP review, it seems it's back to normal. Really strange scenario, though.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me using Chrome 80.0.3987.149 it look like this.

Note my formatting is different e.g. the "Meta" banner is in a different place, i.e. at the top of the page, whereas yours isn't?

[image]

Comment: Here's a [more full view of how the page looks for me](https://i.imgur.com/hBYHom6.png).